# AutoResizing a certain column rows

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

This gives me an error when i set the sizes of the rows in a specific column.

```
Public Sub Multi_LineGrid(ByRef List As DataGridView)
    Try
        List.Columns(1).AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeRowsMode.DisplayedCells
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub
```

The error in this code is

> The value of argument 'value'(11) is invalid for Enum type
>   'DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMoe'. Parameter name: value.

Comment: Added the error message @MatSnow

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to assign the `DataGridViewAutoSizeRowsMode.DisplayedCells`-value to a column, but this is a value for the **rows** AutoSize-mode.

It should rather be `DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.DisplayedCells`.

Comment: yes, it does not give an error when i change a to a column value. I want to know what is the right code for auto sizing all the rows in a specific column.

Comment: You can't resize rows only for a specific column. How should that look like?

Comment: There is a column that every row has a very long text and the other columns has fewer text. I want now is there is only a specific columns of rows that will follow the length for all the column so that the very long text column will show only a fewer text.

Comment: Your text is really unclear, I'm not sure if i understand correctly. You want to set the column-width to fit the length of the text in a specific row? Please edit the question and add information so it is clear what you're trying to achieve.